# How to generate Flyway migration script from model class in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, database-migration, flyway

In a Java app, I have a model class and I want to generate Flyway migration script from it. There is a useful plugin called **JPABuddy**, but I unable to generate migration script using the same (it only detects the index part even when I delete the corresponding table). So, how can I generate migration script in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @AmitDash What about any answer?

Comment: Sorry, with the current context it is difficult to understand your problem. Hope you can share code / logs for people to be able to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in order for Flyway to work you need to have a base database schema. After which you could add other schema changes.

I think the best way forward for you here would be to create a DB schema using JPA by adding below properties in properties file.

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-source=metadata
```

Then you can use the create.sql as the base DB schema for Flyway migration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. How can I generate `create.sql` for my database?

Comment: I believe you already have the entities on your spring project. Just by using these above configurations you should be able to generate create.sql on your project root.

Comment: You could follow [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-generate-db-schema) sample project